# How to disable app orientation in Xcode 13+ (swift 5+)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to lock app **orientation** to a specific mode in Xcode 13?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's a screenshot of Xcode. This UI is where you can define it globally, or you can do it programmatically, as already someone else has answered.

Additionally, you can configure the iPad here in Target -> build settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1. Lock orientation to a specific mode** *i.e Portrait*

In your AppDelegate, take a variable as

```
var restrictRotation:UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
```

and paste this override function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        return self.restrictRotation
    }
```

**2. Lock orientation for a `UIViewController`**

In your AppDelegate, take a variable as

```
var restrictRotation:UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .all
```

and paste this override function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        return self.restrictRotation
    }
```

And very importantly call the below line from `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` method

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).restrictRotation = .portrait
```